# dbWriteTable with different column names between data.frame and database

Tags: r, rpostgresql, r-dbi

Version 0.4 of the `dbWriteTable` package allowed to copy a `data.frame` to a database table even if the column names of the two objects did not match. Current version (0.6) instead throws an error in such a situation.

Is there a way to bypass the control over the names, or necessarily the column names of the `data.frame` and the database's table must coincide?